# remove slashes jquery from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I send data via ajax so:

```
$res = array();
foreach($series as $i){
    //print_r($i);
    array_push($res, $i);
}
//print_r ($res);
print (json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

Get data:

```
success: function(json){
alert(JSON.stringify(json));
json = json.replace("\\", " ");
alert(JSON.stringify(json));
```

It is alerting same datas, why? How can I remove slashes from json? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP code returning JSON in to String not in Object

Use `JSON.parse` instead of `JSON.stringify()`

Replace success function like this:

```
success: function(json){
alert(JSON.parse(json));
//json = json.replace("\\", " ");
alert(json);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: @zeitgeist Accept it if it is useful

Comment: I accepted it in 2 min, there are some time  constraints here UpD: done=)

Answer (score 0):

`json.stringify` returns the data as string.so you need to parse it to get in array format which will remove slashes automatically.

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);

alert(data);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you have to parse your string and after that you can use json.replace**

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John\\" }' );
var myname=obj.name ;
myname.replace("|","");
```