# Extracting a string from a response text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to extract just the response from the following response

```
"{"Message":"Looks like you need to login"}"
```

I tried to stringyfy it as follows

```
var response = "{"Message":"Looks like you need to login"}";
var json_response = JSON.stringify(response);
```

But my response ends up looking something like this.

```
"{\"Message\":\"Looks like you need to login\"}"
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? and how I can extract just the message by doing something like

`json_response.Message` perhaps?

Comment: Don't `stringify` a `string`, you need to `parse` a `string`. `JSON -> object = parse`, `object -> JSON = stringify`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: SO answer already there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26906538/2777098

Comment: You just need to Parse the json string to Javascript Object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `JSON.parse()`:

```
var str = "{\"Message\":\"Looks like you need to login\"}";
var json = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(json.Message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var response = { Message: "Looks like you need to login" } ;
var json_response = JSON.stringify( response ) ;
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parse() method of json which is very  useful. So keep using that it is very light weighted.

Here is my answer :

```
var myString = "{\"Message\":\"Looks like you need to login\"}";
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(myString);
alert(parsedJson.Message);
```